# Cisco Packet Tracer simple ASA configuration

Tags: networking, router, routing

I want to configure a simple network with a Cisco ASA as you see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNYFn.png).

The aim is that two PCs can see each other and ping without any problem.

I configured IP's (static) as you see in the picture and for ASA I passed these steps:

1. Removing DHCP from ASA

In ASA's CLI console:

2. ```
   interface vlan 1
   nameif inside
   ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0
   security-level 100
   ```
  3.

```
interface vlan 2
nameif outside
ip address 203.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
security-level 0
```

4. ```
   interface et 0/0
   switchport access vlan 1
   ```
  5.

```
interface et 0/1
switchport access vlan 2
```

6. ```
   route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 203.1.1.1
   ```
  7.

```
access-list myaccess extended permit tcp any any
access-list myaccess extended permit icmp any any
access-group mylist in interface outside
```

But when I ping `192.168.1.2` from `172.16.1.2` (or vice versa), it results in a request timeout.
(IP for the router & PCs and default gateways for PCs are set correctly)

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can the PCs ping their respective router interface IP?

Comment: @DanielK Yes, 172.16.1.2 can ping 172.16.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 can ping the router (both IPs)

Comment: then I would suggest your problem lies in routing. Check the routing table on **each** device.

Comment: @DanielK I don't know what routing table is, you mean ASA is configured properly? I thought I didn't configure it right.

Comment: 'show route' on Cisco ASA; 'route print' on Windows. There is a good article on routing here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/route_overview.html